# Properly Removing .deb Files

Tags: shell, unix, debian

I installed LibreOffice on a server with a shell script using the following

```
sudo -S dpkg -r LibreOffice_5.1.1.3_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS/*.deb
```

Now I would like to change to a different version and am attempting to uninstall the previous version by using:

```
sudo -S dpkg -i LibreOffice_5.0.6.3_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS/*.deb
```

which yields the error

> dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by
>   quoting the names of the files they come in

After doing some research I found this [thread](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=40312) and it seems I will need to call the `dpkg` with the name of the actual debian files, but doing `dpkg -r libreoffice` results in the error

> dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libreoffice which isn't
>   installed

I have also tried using `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core`, which does not seem to be successful.  Is there an automated way to remove all of the installed .deb files so that I can safely install the new version?

For reference the following files are shown in the `DEBS` folder

> libobasis5.1-base_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-filter-data_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-xsltfilter_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-calc_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-gnome-integration_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-core_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-graphicfilter_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-base_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-draw_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-images_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-calc_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-en-us_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-impress_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-debian-menus_5.1.1-3_all.deb
>   libobasis5.1-en-us-base_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-kde-integration_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-dict-en_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-en-us-calc_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-librelogo_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-dict-es_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-en-us-math_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-math_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-dict-fr_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-en-us-res_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-ogltrans_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-draw_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-en-us-writer_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-onlineupdate_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-en-us_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-extension-beanshell-script-provider_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-ooofonts_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-impress_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-extension-javascript-script-provider_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-ooolinguistic_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-math_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-extension-mediawiki-publisher_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-postgresql-sdbc_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-ure_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-extension-nlpsolver_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-python-script-provider_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libreoffice5.1-writer_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-extension-pdf-import_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-pyuno_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-extension-report-builder_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb
>   libobasis5.1-writer_5.1.1.3-3_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dpkg-query -l` to get a list of installed packages. You can also search the list with `dpkg-query -l 'libre*'` for everything beginning with 'libre'.

You can then use the displayed package name to remove or purge them with dpkg.

Using `dpkg --remove PackageNameHere` will let configuration files untouched and delete only the binaries.
With `dpkg --purge AgainYourPackageNameHere` you would delete everything regarding the package.

Answer (score 0):

we can also use dpkg-query - W to list the installed packages.
For example to search for installed sqlectron

$>dpkg-query -W 'sqlec**'
sqlectron 1.37.1

then you can delete the package using dpkg -r|--remove 'package-name' or dpkg -P|--purge 'package-name' command.